# this vs classname for accessing static in typescript

Tags: typescript

In typescript, I have noticed that the following approaches are both valid for accessing a static class member.

```
class MyClass
{
   private static readonly FOO: string = "foo";

   public DoSomething(): void { console.log(MyClass.FOO);}
   public DoSomethingWithThis(): void { console.log(this.FOO); }
}

var instance: MyClass = new MyClass();
instance.DoSomething();
instance.DoSomethingWithThis();
```

Is there a more correct way? Having come from a C++/C# background, by default, I would always use "DoSomething()" over "DoSomethingWithThis()"

Comment: Interestingly, when I run this in typescript playground on v4.5.3, DoSomethingWithThis() doesn't work - so clearly the answer is `DoSomething()` is the correct approach - but I wonder if this is something that has changed?

Both approaches _compile_  - but `DoSomethingWithThis()` returns undefined.

Comment: When I paste your example into the typescript playground v4.5.3, [https://tsplay.dev/NddevN](https://tsplay.dev/NddevN), `this.FOO` causes a compiler error, even though it still compiles the file.

Comment: Per my previous comment, you can access static properties from static methods https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#calling_static_members_from_another_static_method

Comment: Is there a genuine case for using `this.FOO` even in the static method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is allowed, accessing static properties from static methods

```
class MyClass
{
   private static readonly FOO: string = "foo";

   public DoSomething(): void { console.log(MyClass.FOO);}
   public static DoSomethingWithThis(): void { console.log(this.FOO); } // this
}
```

This is not allowed

```
var instance: MyClass = new MyClass();
instance.DoSomethingWithThis(); // Property 'DoSomethingWithThis' does not exist on type 'MyClass'.
// Did you mean to access the static member 'MyClass.DoSomethingWithThis' instead?
```

But you could do this

```
MyClass.DoSomethingWithThis(); // Static method uses static property.
```

> Is there a more correct way?

The correct way depends of your use case, but as you can see, you can't call `this.FOO` in `DoSomethingWithThis` unless it's also declared as static.